# Sequence nodes in network visualization in R

Tags: javascript, r

I am looking for an R package that is used for network graph visualizations, but can take string sequences as nodes. For example:

```
AAAAATAAA
    /
   /
  /
ATAAAAAA
```

or

```
AAAAATTTTAAA
     |---|
       /
      /
     /
 |---|
ATTTTAAAAAA
```

Each sequence is a node, but the edges point to one particular letter in the sequence, or group or letters ( in this example the T's). I have found a variety of packages that offer different shapes (circles, squares, triangles, etc) for nodes, but not this kind of functionality. Does anybody know of a R package that does this? Or maybe a JavaScript package that does and there (hopefully) is an [HTMLWidgets](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/) wrapper for it.